# How can I create a progress bar in one cell based on the value in another

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I want to put a progress bar in a cell which shows how long an object is going to remain in a state and also put the name of the state in the cell, so it shows both pieces of information.  I can't work out how to get the progress bar to base its length on the value in another cell.  Any help/suggestions welcome.

Comment: I will be helpful to see the code you've tried and what specifically went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `REPT` worksheet function. It repeats text a certain number of times.

`=REPT("X",A2)`

Repeats "X" the number of times as the number in cell A2. As cell A2 changes, the number of X's will change.